# does nolearn/lasagne support python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, theano

I am working with Neural Net implementation in `nolearn.lasagne` as mentioned [here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ottogroup/kaggle/blob/master/Otto_Group_Competition.ipynb)
However I get the following error:
`ImportError: No module named 'cPickle'`
I figure out that `cPickle` is `pickle` in python-3
Does nolearn/lasagne support python-3 ? If not, is there any workaround ?

Comment: It looks like Lasagne moved out of nolearn to a separate project. It [passes its own tests](https://travis-ci.org/Lasagne/Lasagne) on Python 3.4.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You seem to be using an older version of nolearn.  Try the current master from Github with these commands:

`pip uninstall nolearn
pip install https://github.com/dnouri/nolearn/archive/master.zip#egg=nolearn`

Here's the tests in master running with both Python 2.7 and 3.4: https://travis-ci.org/dnouri/nolearn/builds/61806852